# Ajax not working in CodePen

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codepen

I'm doing the Wikipedia Viewer project from freeCodeCamp. For some reason, the ajax function isn't working because nothing shows up in the console on click. The code for it is shown below. Thanks in advance to anyone who sees this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("search").click(function() {
    var searchTerm = $("searchTerm").val();
    var url1 = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=" + searchTerm + "&format=json&callback=?";
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: url1,
      async: false,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(errorMessage) {
        alert("Error");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: $("search") - Is it a `class` or an `id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recheck the `search` and `searchTerm`. Are they `id` or `class`?

1. For a class, write `$(".search")`
2. For an id, write `$("#search")`

The following code works for me.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search").click(function() {
    var searchTerm = "usa";
    var url1 = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=" + searchTerm + "&format=json&callback=?";
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: url1,
      async: false,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(errorMessage) {
        alert("Error");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="search">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an issue with your jQuery selector. Make sure you are loading jQuery also.

```
$("searchTerm") tries to find <searchTerm>
```

and

```
$("search") tries to find <search>
```

Try using IDs and Classes like..

```
$('#search') looks for <input type="text" id="search">
$('.search') looks for <input type="text" class="search">
$('input[type="text"]') looks for <input type="text">

$('#searchBtn') looks for <button id="search">Click Me</button>
$('.searchBtn') looks for <button class="search">Click Me</button>
$('button') looks for <button>Click Me</button>
```

The important part to note here is classes and IDs can be used to select most types of elements. So #search could be a button, text input, textarea, anything. Or you can select an element, like what you were trying to do.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/gfa6agok/9/ - you will see console output

Comment: shouldn't the button id just be ```search``` not ```#search```?

Answer (score 0):

**In this area of your code:**

```
  $("search").click(function() {
    var searchTerm = $("searchTerm").val();
```

Are you using a class or ID?
If you are using a class the search and searchTerm would have a dot (.) in front of it like this:

```
  $(".search").click(function() {
    var searchTerm = $(".searchTerm").val();
```

If you are using an ID the search and searchTerm would have a number sign (#) in front of it like this:

```
  $("#search").click(function() {
    var searchTerm = $("#searchTerm").val();
```